# Sqoop more than 2 billion records

Tags: oracle, sqoop, cloudera

I noticed that sqoop limits extraction from Oracle (or generally?) to 2147483000 records per session, as this guy also experienced http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Sqoop-job-limiting-number-of-rows/m-p/64247

Is there any setting change we can enable to extract all? Or do I have limit using filter conditions.

Comment: Normally if you run into limits of a system you are doing something wrong. What are you trying to do?

Comment: We have an Oracle table that we are trying to migrate/archive into Cloudera. The table has 4-5 billion records. The table has no key nor any index.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue but after getting deep into the documentation I realized that the one mapper can only sqoop 2147483000 records. So technically you need to bump up the number of mappers. The code I used to sqoop down 2247948942 records is as follows, both methods tend to work, but I think -m is what you need.

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=7782 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx6225m --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection --username anair[COMMON] -password-file /user/anair/pw/sqoop.password --as-textfile --table COMMON.LABRESULTID_XREF_IOT_H641171 --target-dir /user/anair/prod/202002/labresult_xref/m_16/H641171 -m 16  

sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=7782 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx6225m --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbConnection --username anair[COMMON] -password-file /user/anair/pw/sqoop.password --as-textfile  --table COMMON.LABRESULTID_XREF_IOT_H641171 --target-dir /user/anair/prod/202002/labresult_xref/m_16_v2/H641171 -m 16 --split-by CLIENT_DS_ID
```